# GitLab project (repository) quota

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ce

I am running a [GitLab Community Edition](https://about.gitlab.com/features/#community) and would like to add a quota to the GitLab projects (repositories) to prevent users from creating large projects.

The quota should be in terms of max project size, e.g. 420 MB per project. Is this possible? If yes, how can I configure GitLab accordingly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That was [suggested in the old feedback forum](http://feedback.gitlab.com/forums/176466-deprecated-feedback-forum/suggestions/5338816-limit-size-of-the-repositories-of-one-user) in 2014 ("limit size of the repositories of one user").
And again in the [official GitLab issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/3739#note_2822810) for different context: "Ability to restrict file size / disk space for LFS" (Large File Storage)

This is <del>not yet implemented</del> (February 2016, GitLab 8.4.x)
It is now [implemented with GitLab 8.12](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/admin_area/settings/account_and_limit_settings.html#repository-size-limit) (September 2016), but only for GitLab EE, as noted by [Matthias Weiler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1066210/matthias-weiler) in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45298082/6309).

Comment: Ok, thanks for the information. I hope, this will be a feature in the future.

Answer (score 4):

This is implemented in [GitLab Enterprise Edition](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/admin_area/settings/account_and_limit_settings.html#repository-size-limit). According to [this issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/19374) it is not planned to be added to the Community Edition.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't pay for GitLab EE, you can use this strategy:

- Add a pre-receive hook, as a Global Hook for All Repositories (https://docs.gitlab.com/12.4/ee/administration/custom_hooks.html#set-a-global-git-hook-for-all-repositories) and set a script to check size as this question ([How to prevent a Git repository growing above a maximum size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47791509/how-to-prevent-a-git-repository-growing-above-a-maximum-size?noredirect=1&lq=1))