# How to prevent a Git repository growing above a maximum size?

Tags: git

There is a repository where you need to control its size and in case of exceeding the limit - block any changes. How to implement this?

Comment: If you reach the threshhold and block, then how will your development work continue?  I think a better approach is to make sure that you keep really large and bad stuff out of the repo, e.g. large binary files.

Comment: The task is to deliberately limit the size of the git repository.

Comment: Instead of solving the problem by blocking, have you already looked at Git Virtual File System? https://github.com/Microsoft/GVFS This allows immense repositories to work perfectly.

Comment: You could use a hook to check the combined size of tracked files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to limit file size on commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39576257/how-to-limit-file-size-on-commit)

Comment: There was an idea to use the hook "update" on the server, and the size to be read by means of git or OS.

Comment: Simply monitor the git repository and when it grows beyond the target size revoke push access for everyone.

Comment: Also note that "the size of a repository" is a finicky thing since garbage collection and packing can make it go down as well. For instance, after growing to/beyond the target size, what if I force-push a branch back in time to get rid of commits, or delete some branches? Should you then allow changes yet again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**.git/hooks/pre-receive**

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# size limit 2(Gb)
sizelimit_gb=2

reposize_kb=`git count-objects -v | grep 'size-pack' | sed  's/.*\(size-pack:\).//'`
let reposize_b=$reposize_kb*1024
let sizelimit_b=$sizelimit_gb*1024*1024*1024

if [ $reposize_b -gt $sizelimit_b ]; then
    echo "Error: repository size > $sizelimit_gb Gb"
    exit 1
#else
#    echo "<= $sizelimit_gb Gb"
fi

exit 0
```

Above script must be saved as `.git/hooks/pre-receive` in server, with execution permissions enabled (`chmod +x .git/hooks/pre-receive`).

Comment: I am getting a warning while running this script "warning: no corresponding .idx or .pack: /data/gitlab/git-data/repositories/@hashed/27/82/2782526eaa0c5c254b36d0c90e1f8c06af41d167a8b539bd3c81cd6d155e7e5f.git/objects/pack/pack-01293e2926b1a7766dae5863003f065107c78c32.bitmap"
 And Repo size is coming 0 instead of the actual size which is around 3GB something

Comment: please help me in this @Dima Kodnik